# ScreenShot en Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Buen día estoy teniendo problemas con los screenshots dentro de la app no debería de dejar que se hicieran, tengo entendido que de manera nativa en swift no se puede bloquear esta función, por lo que tengo entendido solo se puede ejecutar el esto userDidTakeScreenshotNotification que sirve para detectar cuando alguien tomo una captura.
Después de investigar tuve una posible solución que es borrar la ultima foto del dispositivo después de que se toma el screen el problema que tengo es que pide autorización para hacerlo mi código es el siguiente:

```
func detectScreenShot() {
       UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
        
        let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in
            
            let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)
                if (fetchResult.lastObject != nil) {
                    let lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject! as PHAsset
                    let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: lastAsset)
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges( {
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
                        completionHandler: {
                            success, error in
                            print("Se borro la foto,")
                    })

                }
        }
    }
```

Funciona bien y se ejecuta correctamente solo que pide autorización para eliminar la foto hay alguna manera de omitir este paso y que se borre directo.
O editar de alguna manera la foto para que aparezca de un color solido
de ante mano gracias.

Comment: Apple es bien estricto en temas de privacidad y que elimines algo sin una confirmación no lo veo posible. Aún así si lo lograras estoy seguro que Apple no aprueba tu app para el AppStore.

Comment: Entiendo esa parte, habra algún otro método o maña para evitar o restringir estas acciones

Comment: Pienso que no la hay, si quieres que no copien lo que va a mostrar la app deberías patentar todo el contenido o colocar marcas de agua. Sería la única forma.

Comment: Ni modo, de igual forma muchas gracias.